# How to set 2 digits after comma in react useForm library?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set 2 digits after comma. How i can do this ? My component is below.

```
<Input
  name='cost'
  error={ errors }
  rules={ register({ required: true }) }
/>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample format? 2 digits after comma means what?

Comment: Something like that 10.34 not 10.347980

Comment: . Is called period. Do you mean that in the input field you can only type 2 digit after period or whatever you type you want to parse it as 2 digit after period?

Comment: @moshfiqrony yes i want  2 digit after period.